# Can I add an urgent status to PHP mail send function so the password reset is not expired when the user receives it?

Tags: php, token, sendmail, forgot-password

I'm currently using tokens and a bit of code that expires  $expires = date("U") + 1800; So roughly 30 mins after the user requests the link. The PHP send function gets an email to any address in my domain in a few seconds, however, any other domains, such as a Gmail account, can take up to 40 mins or so. Is there a way to increase the priority of the reset link email in my PHP script? Or do I have to simply increase the token expiration and lower my security slightly?

Thank you!

I've tried changing the $from and $header info with no positive results. I've also done a ton of googling and searching on overstack. I'm mostly finding info on how to set up a basic send function, which I've already got.

...

```
  $expires = date("U") + 1800;

  require 'config.php';

  $userEmail = $_POST["email"];

  $sql = "DELETE FROM pwdReset WHERE pwdResetEmail=?";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "There was an error!";
    exit();
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userEmail);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO pwdReset (pwdResetEmail, pwdResetSelector, pwdResetToken, pwdResetExpires) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "There was an error!";
    exit();
  } else {

    $hashedToken = password_hash($token, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $userEmail, $selector, $hashedToken, $expires);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }

  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysqli_close($link);

  $to = $userEmail;

  // Subject
  $subject = 'Reset your mydomainhere password';

  // Message
  $message = 'We recieved a password reset request for your account. If you did not make this request, please disregard this email. Your password reset link is:';
  $message .= '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a></p>';

  // Headers
  $headers = "From: The mydomainhere Team <info@mydomainhere.org>\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: info@mydomainhere.org\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

  // Send e-mail
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  header("Location: https://www.mydomainhere.org/login/forgotPass.php?reset=success");
    } else {
        header("Location: https://www.mydomainhere.org/login/forgotPass.php?reset=error");
        exit();
}
```

The PHP mail function is working, it's just taking longer than expected to send. I'm hoping to add some kind of urgent tag to the message so outside servers will accept it faster.

Comment: You don't have any real control over how quickly something may be delivered. Something like an `urgent` status is only a visual clue to the recipient. The path between your server and the receiving server doesn't look at, or care about, something like that.

Comment: Bummer, I was worried that might be the case. Thank you for your response.

Comment: yes, agreed with dave there is different server and they have a different response time. some servers are really slow and take longer time. you cannot control the third party server. but there is more than one way to increase security you can send security message on both email and mobile number to increase the security... you can also ask security question answer after the securty email part(2-step verification).

Comment: Aside: if your reset tokens are randomly generated you don't need to hash them. Hashing combats brute-forcing, but brute-forcing a random string with sufficient entropy isn't possible to begin with. So you can safe yourself a bunch of CPU cycles if you do something like `$token = base64_encode(random_bytes(16));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add an urgent status to PHP mail send function so the password reset is not expired when the user receives it?

No, there is no "expedited delivery" for emails. The "Urgency" header exists, but has no effect on delivery. (Its only effect is to display a flag on the message in some clients.)

If it's taking "up to 40 mins or so" for some of your messages to be delivered to GMail, something is wrong with your mail servers, and that needs to be addressed. This isn't a problem with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm looking into using PHPMailer() instead of mail(). Upon further investigation that works better with gmail servers.